# Are Vaishnavastra and Narayanastra the same?

Tags: narayanastra

Narayanastra was used by Ashwatthama and its effects are described.

Vaishnavastra was used on Arjuna but Krishna took it upon himself and it is said to have turned into a garland.

Are they same weapon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### As per Śiva Purāṇa, Vaiṣṇavāstra and the Nārāyaṇāstra are two different weapons.

Goddess Kālī & demon Śaṅkhacūḍa hurled them at each other.

> [Chapter 38](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226179.html) - Kālī fights,  Rudra-saṃhitā (5): Yuddha-khaṇḍa, Śivapurāṇa
>
> Sanatkumāra said:—
>
> .....
>
> दृष्ट्वा कालीं शंखचूडश्शीघ्रमाजौ समाययौ । दानवाश्च भयं प्राप्ता राजा
> तेभ्योऽभयं ददौ ॥ ५ ॥
>
> > 5. On seeing Kālī, Śaṅkhacūḍa hastened to the battle ground. The Dānavas were frightened but the king Śaṅkhacūḍa assured them of
> >    protection.
>
> ---
>
> काली चिक्षेप वह्निं च प्रलयाग्निशिखोपमम् । राजा जघान तं शीघ्रं
> **वैष्णवांकितलीलया** ॥ ६ ॥
>
> > 6. Kālī hurled fire as fierce as the flame of dissolution which the king put out sportively by means of **Vaiṣṇava missiles**.
>
> ---
>
> **नारायणास्त्रं** सा देवी चिक्षेप तदुपर्यरम् । वृद्धिं जगाम तच्छस्त्रं
> दृष्ट्वा वामं च दानवम् ॥ ७ ॥
>
> > 7. Immediately the goddess hurled the **Nārāyaṇa missile** at him. The missile developed its power on seeing the Dānava Śaṅkhacūḍa.
>
> ---
>
> तं दृष्ट्वा शंखचूडश्च प्रलयाग्निशिखोपमम् । पपात दंडवद्भूमौ प्रणनाम
> पुनःपुनः ॥ ८ ॥
>
> > 8. On realising it as fierce as the flame of fire of dissolution, the Dānava Śaṅkhacūḍa fell flat on the ground and bowed again and again.
>
> ---
>
> निवृत्तिं प्राप तच्छ्स्त्रं दृष्ट्वा नम्रं च दानवम् । ब्रह्मास्त्रमथ
> सा देवी चिक्षेप मंत्रपूर्वकम् ॥ ९ ॥
>
> > 9. On seeing the Dānava humbled the missile turned away. Then the goddess hurled the Brahmā missile with due invocation through the
> >    mantra.
>
> English Translation by J.L. Shastri

---

A similar Story with almost the same sets of weapons, but maintaining a categorical difference between Vaiṣṇavāstra and the Nārāyaṇāstra, has been narrated in [Chapter 19th](https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/n299/mode/2up?view=theater), Khaṇḍaḥ 2 - Prakṛti-khaṇḍaḥ), Brahmavaivarta  Purāṇa

> माहेश्वरं प्रचिक्षेप काली वह्निशिखोपमम् । राजा जघान तच्छीघ्रं **वैष्णवेन
> च लीलया ॥ ५० ॥ नारायणास्त्रं सा देवी** चिक्षिपे मन्त्रपूर्वकम् । राजा
> ननाम तं दृष्ट्वा चावरुह्य रथादहो ॥ ५१ ॥ ऊर्ध्वं जगाम तच्छस्त्रं
> प्रलयाग्निशिखोपमम् । पपात शङ्खचूडश्च भक्त्या वै दण्डवद्भुवि ।
> ब्रह्मास्त्रं सा च चिक्षेप यत्नतो मन्त्रपूर्वकम् ॥ ५२ ॥ ब्रह्मास्त्रेण
> महाराज निर्वाणं च चकार ह ॥
>
> > **The goddess Kāli then used the Mahesvarāstra which was like a fire
> > flame. The king neutralized the same with the use of Vaiṣṇavāstra.**
> > **The goddess then shot Nārāyanāstra reciting the mantras. The king
> > bowed in reverence before it and at once got down from the chariot.**
> > The weapon rushed like the fire of dissolution and reached before the
> > demon king who in utter devotion prostrated before it on the ground.
> > Thereafter the goddess with great efforts shot the Brahmästra which
> > was neutralized by the demon king by shooting another Brahmästra.
> > The Goddess again used the divine weapon, which was neutralized by the
> > demon king by shooting another divine weapon. The goddess then made
> > use of Shakti which was a yojana in length. The king on the other hand
> > broke it into a hundred pieces with the use of his sharp weapons.
>
> English Translation by Shanti Lal Nagar

---

#### So, no they are not same weapons. Both the Vaiṣṇavāstra and the Nārāyaṇāstra are two different weapons

Comment: just HOW do you find all these references, so quickly, too !!!!!!!!!!!!  So is narayanastra always defended against by surrendering to it @vivikta ?

Comment: Haha, luckily I happen know and have read a drop of the vast literature on Hinduism , and yes, good hands at keyboard and mouse helps a lot. :P And yes, there's no counter to Narayanastra except unequivocal surrender unto it, or Narayana himself! @SK

Comment: @SK You can search [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/) and find easily.