# Which astras can be countered by surrendering to them?

Tags: weapon, narayanastra

In the answer to this question

[Are Vaishnavastra and Narayanastra the same?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51152/are-vaishnavastra-and-narayanastra-the-same)

It is stated that Narayanastra can be made harmless by surrendering to it.

Usually astras are countered by the same astra or by a counter-astra (Varunastra against Agneyastra etc.).

Is there any other weapon besides Narayanastra that can be countered by surrendering to it?

Comment: Only Narayanastra